# How can one add a string to all items in a table

Tags: r

I am creating a table from 2 vectors, converting the values to percentages and then I need to add the "%" symbol at the end.

```
my.table <- table(vecA, vecB)
my.table <- round(prop.table(my.table, margin = 2) * 100, digits = 2)
```

I tried the paste command and explored with the sep and collapse arguments but the returned data structure is not a table any more, but a vector of characters.

Answer (score 1):

```
my.table <- apply(round(prop.table(my.table, margin = 2) * 100, digits = 2), 1, paste0, '%')
```

or you could use the premade `percent` function in the `scales` package

```
my.table <- apply(prop.table(my.table, margin = 2), 1, scales::percent)
```

If you want it as a table and not just a matrix you can use `as.table` on the result.